# Receiving data from Arduino to Android. Data is wrong

Tags: android, arduino

Hi I trying to receive data from Arduino to Android phone. The Android coding is below: 
[App crashed due to looper.prepare() in the beginlistendata() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252203/app-crashed-due-to-looper-prepare-in-the-beginlistendata-function/34252375?noredirect=1#comment56247520_34252375)

The Arduino code is below:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  eHealth.initPulsioximeter();

  //Attach the inttruptions for using the pulsioximeter.   
  PCintPort::attachInterrupt(6, readPulsioximeter, RISING);
}

void loop() {

  delay(500);
  Serial.print("PRbpm : "); 
  Serial.print(eHealth.getBPM());

  Serial.print("    %SPo2 : ");
  Serial.print(eHealth.getOxygenSaturation());

  Serial.print("\n");  
  Serial.println("============================="); 
  delay(500);

}//end of void loop
```

I am getting ============ Spo2 flashing very fast on my Android phone. And Also I am not receiving the updated value like I was supposed to receive Spo2 99 but I am getting Spo2: 0

Also how do I pass the data to other activity?

Comment: Can you plz give me a brief idea over Arduino ?

Comment: @AndroidDev I am actually using Arduino Uno 3 with a  e-health sensor platform and trying to send SPo2 and heart rate value to a smart phone. The link of the platform is here. https://www.cooking-hacks.com/ehealth-sensors-complete-kit-biometric-medical-arduino-raspberry-pi/ Right now I am able to receive Rbpm and %SPo2 and ======== but they flashed very fast. But not the value.

Comment: @AndroidDev I sending my data in a loop from arduino.

Comment: It looks like the problem is your not getting values from the eHealth sensor not the link between android and arduino

Comment: did you add the readPulsioximeter function and just not show it or did you leave it out all together ?

Comment: @user1244302 Hi when I display it on the Arduino serial monitor I am able to display the correct values and also when I send it to the blueterm app(download from google play) I am able to receive the correct/updated values. But I am not getting the updated/correct values of the pulse oximeter when I used my own code.

Comment: Serial.print(eHealth.getBPM());   Serial.print(eHealth.getOxygenSaturation()); These two parts  read the values from pulse oximeter.

Comment: @user1244302 hey you are right! Apparently the Arduino part got some problem. I restart everything and replug my sensor now I getting the Spo2 and heart rate values.